# Bug With Firefox - Disabled Attribute of Input Not Resetting When Refreshing

Tags: html, firefox, input, textbox

I've found what I believe to be a bug with Firefox and I'm wondering if this actually is a bug, as well as any workarounds for this.

If you create a basic webpage with the following source:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <input id="txtTest" type="text" />
      <input type="button" onclick="$('#txtTest').attr('disabled','disabled');" value="Set Disabled (jQuery)" />
      <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('txtTest').disabled = true;" value="Set Disabled (js)" />
      <input type="button" onclick="$('#txtTest').removeAttr('disabled');" value="Remove Disabled" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you `disable` the `textbox` dynamically and then refresh the page, the `textbox` will remain disabled instead of resetting back to its original state of not disabled. I've tried this in IE8 and Chrome and those behave as I would expect, resetting the `textbox` back to not disabled when I refresh.

Another interesting bit of information is that it still does the same thing if the input is a `checkbox` instead of a `textbox`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the Firefox "feature" where it remembers the state of `input` elements when you simply refresh?

Comment: @thirtydot: I was wondering about that too, so I also tried experimenting with dynamically setting the "size" attribute, and that does get reset upon refresh, just like all the other browsers. So it looks like what I've discovered so far is that Firefox will retain the disabled attribute as well as the actual value of the input, but not the size...

Comment: Wow, you're right! I set autocomplete="off" on the input and this no longer happens. That's pretty inconvenient that firefox turns that on by default!

Comment: Yeah, I'd forgotten you can disable it with `autocomplete="off"`. [This blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2010/03/22/removing-the-autocomplete-or-f5-refresh-in-firefox-from-remembering-field-values.aspx) looks familiar to me, so I've definitely come across this before. You should write an answer to your own question (or should I?)

Comment: There is an open Mozilla bug report about this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072

Comment: [46845 - Form elements don't reset upon manually reloading page - bugzilla.mozilla.org](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=46845). This report was opened 22 years ago and closed 17 years ago.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

This is a *"feature"* of Firefox which remembers form input values across page refreshes. To fix this behavior, you simply set `autocomplete="off"` on the form containing the inputs, or just directly to the input.

This stops autocomplete from working and prevents the browser from remembering the state of input fields.

Alternatively, you can just "hard-refresh" by clicking CTRL+F5. This will completely reset the current page.

Comment: I just hit this problem when the user clicks the back button, seems like `autocomplete="off"` doesn't work in that case.

Comment: i don't want a form, I just have a single button and Firefox "remembers" it's disabled..annoying. I can reset it via JS but..ugly.

Comment: @vsync Try setting it on the button/input element. Should work, too!

Comment: You even have to do this on buttons. I find it hard to believe that this is a feature and not a bug?

Comment: this also affects hidden inputs also

Comment: This was driving me nuts.  I am using a jQuery button.  Command - Refresh and the button was enabled, but a regular refresh and it was not.  Made no sense, thanks @stephen-mesa.

Comment: Setting it on the **form** is a little over-the-top, but sadly **MDN** says it _ignores the attribute_ on basically all but _type=text_ - the [english page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autocomplete) linked me here, yet the [german page](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-autocomplete) mentions the ignore issue (the autocomplete paragraph is currently still in english!) QUOTE: This attribute is ignored if the value of the type attribute is hidden, checkbox, radio, file, or a button type (button, submit, reset, image).

Comment: First time encountering this issue and your solution worked out of box. But i set it only on the button rather than the whole form, as autocomplete is a great feature for fields too. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

To deal with the back button, do this (from [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=443289))

```
    window.addEventListener('pageshow', PageShowHandler, false);
    window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);

    function PageShowHandler() {
        window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);
    }

    function UnloadHandler() {
        //enable button here
        window.removeEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer has only one up vote while the other answer has 99. Restoring the disabled state on unload is better than disabling autocomplete, since autocomplete is a desirable functionality.

Comment: I think that `//enable button here` is redundant here; my comprehension of referred docs is that simply the *presence* of event listener will prevent the page to be stored in the BFcache.

Comment: Note that adding an unload handler has other side effects in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching#section_5

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed an open [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072) in Firefox. There is also a note in [MDN: `autocomplete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete#Values) (scroll down to the second yellow box):

> Note: The `autocomplete` attribute also controls whether Firefox will — unlike other browsers — [persist the dynamic disabled state and (if applicable) dynamic checkedness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985839/bug-with-firefox-disabled-attribute-of-input-not-resetting-when-refreshing) of an `<input>` element, `<textarea>` element, or entire `<form>` across page loads. The persistence feature is enabled by default. **Setting the value of the `autocomplete` attribute to `off`** disables this feature. This works even when the autocomplete attribute would normally not apply by virtue of its type. See [bug 654072](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072).

If you are using Bootstrap, you might be interested in the

- [comment on the bug report by a Bootstrap team member](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=654072#c30)
- [bug report in the Bootstrap repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/793)
- [note in the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#buttons)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before you need to add `autocomplete="off"` to your buttons.

Here is a `sh`+`perl` snippet to automate this in the case of `<button>`s in your HTML files/templates (under some assumptions):

```sh
find /path/to/html/templates -type f -name '*.html' -exec perl -pi -e \
  's/(?<=<button )(.*?)(?=>)/@{[(index($1,"autocomplete=")!=-1?"$1":"$1 autocomplete=\"off\"")]}/g' \
  {} +
```

The assumptions are:

- Opening `<button>` tags begin and end on the same line. If this is not the case (i.e. they might be split over several lines) then replacing `/g` with `/gs` should help (the [`s` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) causes `.` to match newlines as well)
- Valid HTML (e.g. there are no funny characters between `<` and `>`) and no unescaped greater than (`>`) inside the opening tag.