# Refresh issue in ASP.Net MVC4 view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have code like below in ASP.Net MVC4. and I am using Razor engine.

```
@{
    string sDefaultEnvironId = string.Empty;

} 
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
    function changeHd() {
        $("#hdSelEnvironmentId").val("1");
    }
</script>
<input type="button" value="ChangeHD" onclick="changeHd();" />
@Html.Hidden("hdSelEnvironmentId", sDefaultEnvironId)
```

The value of hidden field `hdSelEnvironmentId` is empty when accessing this view at first time. then it was changed to `1` after I clicked button `ChangeHD`.
But after I pressed `F5`, the value of hidden field `hdSelEnvironmentId` is still `1`, I expected it with initial empty value instead of `1`. Can anyone help me to figure it out ?I just can not understand it. I am using Firefox and Firebug, thanks.

Comment: It is because of browser cache.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov, Thanks, How can I fix it not matter the browser cache enable or not ?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Anyway , How can I disable cache in FireFox. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox keeps form data on reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377301/firefox-keeps-form-data-on-reload)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** [As discovered by Andreas here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377350/1001985), you can remove this behavior by adding an attribute `autocomplete=off` to your input:

```
@Html.Hidden("hdSelEnvironmentId", sDefaultEnvironId, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

---

This effect is *not* due to the cache -- it's a feature (bug?) of Firefox, that when you refresh a page, the inputs of the page do not seem to get re-loaded from the server.

- try the same thing in Chrome or IE, you'll see that the value resets to empty
- clear the cache in Firefox, and you'll notice the value still does not get reset.

So, I'm not sure if there's a workaround, but this issue does seem to be restricted to Firefox.

Comment: IE has the option `check for newer version of stored page`, we can use `every time i visit the webpage` to get the reset content.

Comment: From my personal opinion, Seems Firefox want to give more flexibility to web developer for better performance to parse the HTTP response content?

Answer (score 1):

instead of setting it in

```
 @{
    string sDefaultEnvironId = string.Empty;

}
```

just initialize it in JavaScript.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#hdSelEnvironmentId").val() = "";
    });
    function changeHd() {
            $("#hdSelEnvironmentId").val() = "";   
            $("#hdSelEnvironmentId").val("1");
        }
```

i think this will help.. even on page refresh as document loads again the value will be set to empty and then to 1 on button click