# radio button is not checked on page refresh in firefox

Tags: html, radio-button

```
<div id="btns">
   <input id="r01" type="radio" name="music" checked>
   <input id="r02" type="radio" name="music">
   <input id="r03" type="radio" name="music">
   <input id="r04" type="radio" name="music">
   <input id="r05" type="radio" name="music">
</div>
```

Firefox 24 - `r1` is not checked on page refresh. On Shift-F5 - works.
Chrome - works.

Comment: try `<input id="r01" type="radio" name="music" checked="checked">`

Comment: also, shouldn't the radio buttons has values ?

Comment: @HasanAboShally, `checked='checked'` doesn't work. I don't need values, just for click event.

Comment: It's weird, i know firefox had an issue with radio-buttons, but that was long time ago.. if you only need the click event, then why not using normal buttons ?

Comment: @HasanAboShally, design reasons.

Comment: i would have used css :)

Comment: I believe that html element should be chosen based on their 'meaning' and not how do they look like.. Semantic Web ;)

Comment: @HasanAboShally, the same problem would exist if I have value. It's not my question about using or not, but why the radio doesn't work if I use it ?

Comment: it ma be a FireFox issue (again..)

Answer (score 9):

If it works on shift-F5 it just means, firefox saves the user-input because the form was not sent yet.
[Firefox keeps form data on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377301/firefox-keeps-form-data-on-reload)

> Just found a solution!
>
> Just add autocomplete="off" to all you input and you will solve the problem.
>
> jQuery to solve this on all inputs and textareas

```
$('input,textarea').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a Firefox issue for a long time now.

Set the checked property with javascript when the page loads:

```
window.onload=check;
function check() {
  document.getElementById("r01").checked = true;
}
```