# jQuery Validate plugin button not working, and digits field

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-validate

I've a lot of problem with a simple plugin, jquery validation plugin:
I need to set a form with 3 fields, the name (required) the email (required, email format), the phone (not required, number format of 11 digits).

this is the html:

```
<form class="form" id="contactusform">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-label">
    <label for="cname">Contact Name*</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-row">
    <input id="cname" name="name" type="text" class="form-field" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-label">
    <label for="cemail">Contact Email Address*</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-row">
    <input id="cemail" name="email" type="email"  class="form-field" required>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 form-label">
    <label for="cphone">Contact Phone Number</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-row">
    <input id="cphone" name="phone" type="text" class="form-field">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 form-send-button">
    <div class="">
    <input id="submit" type="button" class="btn send-button" value="SEND">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contactusform").validate({
      rules: {
        name: "required",
        email: {
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        phone: {
            required: false,
            digits: true,
            minlenght: 11
        }
      },
      messages: {
        name: "Please specify your name",
        email: {
            required: "We need your email address to contact you",
            email: "Email must be in the format of name@domain.com"
        },
        phone: {
            minlenght: "please insert a number of 11 digits",
            digits: "The value must be a number"
        }
      }
    });
});
```

I'm using the validator plugin and jquery scripts:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

This code not work properly, I try many times, and the button doesn't seems to work at all. I need to show message under the reuided fields if submit button is clicked without any value in the fields.

Comment: You need `type="submit"`.  `type="button"` is intentionally ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two problems here:**

1. Change `type="button"` into `type="submit"` to get the submit button working.

   ```
   <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn send-button" value="SEND">
   ```
2. You've misspelled the `minlength` rule as `minlenght` both within your `rules` and `messages` options.

   ```
   phone: {
       // required: false,  // superfluous
       digits: true,
       minlength: 11
   }
   ```

**Notes**:

- Since you've included the `additional-methods.js` file, you *could* just used one of the built-in phone number rules instead.

  - `phoneUS`
  - `phoneUK`
  - `phonesUK`
  - `phoneNL`
  - `mobileNL`
  - `mobileUK`
- You do not need to explicitly set `required` to `false`.  Simply leaving out the `required` rule is enough.
- You would use the placeholder, `{0}`, within your custom message.  Then the message automatically uses the same parameter as the rule.

  ```
  minlength: "please insert a number of {0} digits"
  ```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fbhacfy4/**

Comment: Thanks, it works now! a misspelled word made me go crazy! I prefer a custom rule because the required field format does not work with built-in rules. I also removed the additional-methods.js file and it works fine anyway.

Comment: the last thing: how to reset phone input field when refresh page?

Comment: @ufollettu, how do you mean?  If you "refresh" the page, then everything will re-load fresh from scratch.

Comment: is a firefox bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377301/firefox-keeps-form-data-on-reload

Comment: @ufollettu, the "autocomplete" feature is not a "bug" when it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, you just need to change the type of button to `submit`.

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn send-button" value="SEND">
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NP8sS/967/).