# cannot deselect radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with getting a radio button to deselect.

I've got the following buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male">Male</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female">Female</input>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="Unknown">Unknown</input>
```

In the pagebeforeshow I've got:

```
$('input:radio[name=sex]').attr('checked',false);
```

The first time the page displays, no button is selected.  I select a button and dismiss then page and when I redisplay the page the radio button is still selected,

What am I missing?

Some additional details:

In pagebeforeshow I use

$('input:radio[name=sex]:checked').val();

to print out the value of the checked radio button.

The first time the page displays the value is

```
undefined
```

and no radio buttons show as checked when the page display.

I select a radio button and leave the page.  Before I exit the page, I use:

```
$('input:radio[name=sex]').attr('checked',false);
```

to deselect the button.

When I navigate back to the page, pagebeforeshow prints the value as

```
undefined
```

which I expect.

But when the page displays the audio button that was selected when I left the page is still selected.

How could the value print as undefined but the button show as checked when the page display?

Comment: do you mean that its still the same on reload?

Comment: Try `.prop('checked', false)` instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: the fiddle works fine https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/8h2ds5mh/ note that you don't need the closing </input>

Comment: Sounds like you are calling that code before elements exist

Comment: Redisplaying a page doesn't normally select any of the radio buttons if they don't have a `checked` attribute. You must have some other Javascript code that's saving the state in a cookie or localStorage, and then checking the button.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't Firefox [autocomplete inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377301/firefox-keeps-form-data-on-reload) when refreshing a page ? Then OP should use `autocomplete="off"` in its inputs.

Comment: When you say that you redisplay the page, are you talking about using the Back/Forward button, or do you mean the Refresh command that reloads the page? Back and Forward will restore the state of inputs, but reloading doesn't.