# Input 'autocomplete' and 'checked' not working with dynamic value

Tags: php, html

I am grabbing data dynamically in PHP and placing it in the `name` attribute of the input `type="text"`. And based on a condition on the returned data, `type="checkbox"` element is given a `checked` attribute. They display as intended on the first page load.

But even if I 'casually' enter a value in these input fields or change the checkbox status and refresh the page, without submitting the form, these values are saved in the browser somehow and they are displayed rather than the dynamically grabbed data. To tackle this I turned the `autocomplete` attribute `on` for text. Works well, but now the problem is that the dynamic data too is not populated. It leaves the input fields blank.

And also for the `checkbox` field, even though I have the `checked` attribute turned on based on a condition on grabbing data from backend, if I uncheck it and refresh page (without submitting the form) it remains unchecked. They work well on a hard-refresh. What could be the issue? Thank you.

```
<div class="timing">

<?php
foreach ($value as $ky => $val) : ?>

    <?php
        if( strstr( $ky, 'AM' ) ) : ?>
            <input name="<?php echo $ky; ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" class="am" placeholder="am"/>
            <?php 
            elseif( strstr( $ky, 'PM' ) ) :?>
                <input name="<?php echo $ky; ?>" type="number" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" class="pm" placeholder="pm"/> 
    <?php endif; endforeach; ?>
    
</div>
    
<?php 
foreach ($value as $ky => $val) :
    if( strstr( $ky, 'Closed' ) && !empty($val) ) :?>
        <input name="<?php echo $ky; ?>" type="checkbox" class="closed_active closed" checked/>   
<?php 
elseif( strstr( $ky, 'Closed' ) )  : ?>
<input name="<?php echo $ky; ?>" type="checkbox" class="closed"/>   
<?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Does this happen also with [**hard refresh**](https://bacreative.com.au/how-to-hard-refresh-browser-and-clear-cache-using-windows-or-linux/#:~:text=Hold%20the%20Ctrl%20(Control)%20key,key%2C%20click%20the%20Refresh%20button.)?

Comment: @medilies Yeah works on hard refresh.

Comment: sorry I'm a bit confused. do you mean that the problem doesn't happen when you hard refresh ?

Comment: Does that really work? `<?php if( a == b) :?>` Because thats NOT valid PHP syntax I would almost bet the ranch on that

Comment: Most, if not all, browsers will save the form input on refresh, even with autocomplete off. That's just a feature of the browser. A hard refresh clears the page from the browser cache, so the input disappears.

Comment: **ALWAYS Always always!!!** Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @RiggsFolly those a and b values were given just for reference. And if you are referring to the ':' then it's modern PHP in case you weren't aware.  ido it all the time.So do me a favour and remove that down vote if you have done it.

Comment: @medilies, yes you understand correctly. If i change the input values or the checkbox status and do a normal page refresh, these casually entered values still show up and it appears that PHP doesn't grab the values again until I hard refresh the page.

Comment: I am aware how to code an IF, _new and old method_, but variables called `a` and `b` are not legal unless they are defined variable. I think I have said this to you before, WE SEE ONLY WHAT YOU SHOW US, we will debug what you show us. So show us THE READL CODE

Comment: @RiggsFolly you cannot re-create the data grabbing in this scenario. Why are you complicating this? My matter relates to caching issue. Anyway, if you'd still not remove the down-vote, so be it.

Comment: In order for us all to understand this situation I think you need to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can all see it in action. As it stands your question is rather more Essay than Programming related, hence the DV.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried the best I could with my level of english to explain the problem. If still that is not understandable then you are right I cant do anything else. Not to forget, the other guys commenting got exactly what I am trying to explain. So I guess the problem is with your understanding rather than my literature. You may keep your DV as it's free for you and you could enjoy throwing it around at lesser experienced devs. Very motivating and trust instilling for a platform like this indeed.

Comment: If you use Code and not Language, we will all understand it.

Comment: The DV is NOT supposed to de-motivate, it is supposed to police the site to keep its content good. I notice that you are not getting a crowd of people offering answers. So maybe, just maybe I am actually trying to assist you into asking a question in a way that might garner some answers

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you for the effort but I've seen way too many poorly written questions with abominable grammar being up-voted thousand times. Anyway, I don't want to push this further as I am already frustrated with the code where I am stuck. Have it your way.

Comment: So why not simply show us your code

Comment: @RiggsFolly Please check the original post. I've included the code.

Comment: What browsers are you using for testing

Comment: @RiggsFolly Firefox 97.0.1

Comment: Did you read @aynber comment.

Comment: Here are some questions that might be of some help: [Firefox keeps form data on reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7377301/firefox-keeps-form-data-on-reload), [Preventing Firefox from remembering the input value on refresh with a meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486474/preventing-firefox-from-remembering-the-input-value-on-refresh-with-a-meta-tag)