# Django CSS not updating

Tags: css, django

I have this code to refer to my CSS script in my `base.html` for my Django project:

```html
<link href="{% static 'css/project.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

The problem is that whenever I add or remove styling from `project.css`, it doesn’t update when I run the server.

I know this happens because every time the page loads the browser cache will think it’s seen the file before and reload the cached version from disk.
I also know a solution is to change the CSS filename every time I make an update.

Is there an easier way to reload the CSS file every time I refresh my browser?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can bypass the cache using `ctrl + F5`

for detailed reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache

Comment: So it should be fault of Django or just the browser. Too stupid...

Answer (score 20):

You have to click on Ctrl + f5 every time to update your CSS, which isn't dope.
You can actually do something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/mycss.css?{% now "U" %}"/>
```

The {% now "U" %} will generate a random timestamp which updates your CSS every time you reload the page. I hope this works.

For better understanding check out: [click here](http://www.wkoorts.com/wkblog/2009/07/12/css-auto-reload-with-django-templates/)

Answer (score 6):

If you are on mac and using safari, you can press `shift` then press the reload key.

Comment: This actually works. Press `shift` + `cmd` + `R` if you don't want to use the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+f5 for Chrome and Windows helped.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of [Xamuel San](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10565371/xamuel-san), if you are using Jinja to link your stylesheet, then you can try the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='{% static '/css/main.css' %}?{% now "U" %}'>
```

It perfectly worked on Chrome and Firefox. You can also use crtl+f5 to do the same but manually.

Answer (score 2):

Bypass your cache — Simple instructions

In most Windows and Linux browsers:

Hold down **Ctrl** and press **F5**.

In Apple Safari:

Hold down ⇧ Shift and click the Reload toolbar button.
In Chrome and Firefox for Mac:

Hold down both ⌘ Cmd+⇧ Shift and press R.

[know more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache#Bypassing_cache)

Answer (score 2):

It happens during development (when DEBUG is set to True in settings.py) if you change the static files under the directory set STATIC_ROOT, instead of the static directories under the particular app.

In other words, when working locally (on localhost) and DEBUG is set to True, do not forget to change the static files served under your app directory.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome you can press `Ctrl + F5`. If this does not work restart apache

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to temporarily disable the browser cache.

right click => inspect => network

[]Disable cache

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

specify `type` attribute in the `link` tag/field.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/Style.css' %}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers allow you to disable http caching to some degree. In Mozilla, if you're using the Web Developer tools, there's a setting to do this.

[image: Mozilla Web Dev Tool Settings]