# Django: can't load CSS files that are in /static

Tags: css, django, static

Since I finished the backend of my Django website I started adding some style.
My html files are displayed but it seems no css has been linked to them however the path is correct when I show the source code in Firefox.

```
mywebsite/
----blog/
----mywebsite/
----static/
--------css/
------------struct.css
----templates/
--------layouts/
--------errors/
------------404.html
--------html/
------------struct.html
```

Django version: `2.1.7`

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**struct.html:**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/struct.css' %}">

    <title>test</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <p>test</p>


  </body>

</html>
```

**struct.css:**

```
p{
    color:red:
}
body{
    background-color:black:
}
```

Comment: Can you print the whole path in `settings.py`? `print(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"))`

Comment: /home/user/RedPillers/red_pillers/static

Comment: where red_pillers is my project

Comment: It sounds silly but have you tried to set DEBUG=True (locally) of course. Since you haven’t set the STATIC_ROOT and you’re not running collectstatic that might be it. And if it’s then you’ll need to follow the docs.

Comment: Just saw your comment on the answer below. When you're developing (DEBUG=True) what you've done works. However, when you turn DEBUG=False you need to set the STATIC_ROOT as the docs says https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#deployment

Comment: Can it be a matter of the .css not being updated due to using the file stored in cache? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682812/django-css-not-updating/52683195

Answer (score 2):

Generally static files path should be like this appname/static/appname/yourfiles
there is no need to change url patterns.

Assuming your appname is Myapp , the proper path for your css file is

Myapp/static/Myapp/css/struct.css

For including static files , add below line in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

and in your html template

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'Myapp/css/struct.css' %}">
```

If you are having your static files within the app then there is no need to use

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

You can refer [Managing Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/) in django documentation .

Comment: still does not work. By the way the terminal output shows this: [16/Apr/2019 16:12:25] "GET /static/css/struct.css HTTP/1.1" 500 27

Comment: edit: if I turn debug to True, everything works but nothing when it is set to False. why?

Comment: Did you check the source code when your template is rendered , then click the respective link for css in 


<link rel="stylesheet" href="you link" > 


the source code , check whether the file open ... from your comment you are still providing the link in a wrong way , path should be 
static/appname/css/ , since you are getting an error for getting /static/css/struc.css you have done it wrong . Read the steps i mentioned once again and go through the documentation , . check this link for turning off debug 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

Comment: create folder named static inyou app folder , then create another folder with name same as your app , inside that folder put your static files , the steps i mentioned will work

Comment: @qux if you have set debug=false you have to follow  
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

Answer (score 0):

define **static root** in settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/static/'
```

hope it helps

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

Comment: does not help :

Comment: ERRORS:
?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Comment: Correct. STATICFILES_DIRS is the list of **source** folders for fulfilling STATIC_ROOT folder (which is **destination** here) by running `collectstatic`. Just remove STATICFILES_DIRS.  @qux but still don't concatenate strings like grey shown - do it by `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 0):

if you are running this application on localhost then you may try to set DEBUG = True
if you mistakenly set it to False,
Because it was fixed for me that way.