# Django messages not rendering properly

Tags: python, django, django-messages

I am making a project in Django and want to render a styled message if a user fails to input their username/password correctly. The message *does* render, but it doesn't render using the CSS provided for it:

```
ul.messages li.error{                                                                                                                                                                     
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    max-width: 460px;
    color: #D8000C;
    background-color: #FFBABA;
}
```

I'm pretty sure doing ul.messages is overkill, but it's just something I tried. I've also tried .messages .error, .error, etc...

The relevant template code:

```
{% if messages %}                                                                                                                                                             
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Again, the message renders, just not with the relevant CSS. The message call looks like this: `messages.error(request, "Login failed due to incorrect username/password")`

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the actual issue was that the css file was cached by my web browser. See [Django CSS not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682812/django-css-not-updating/52683195) for options for solutions.