# Adding Css in Django templates

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

I have been trying to apply css in the main.css on the class of (custom-card) but its not working. Anyone can find what's the mistake i'm doing. custom-card class is in home.html

Below is the base.html in Django\mysite\blogapp\templates\blog\base.html .

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <!-- CSS link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
</head>

<body>


<!-- ================
  HEADER NAVIGATION
========================= -->

<section class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg ">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span>e-</span>Blog</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto text-center">  <!--ml auto used to have nav on right side,text-center used to make text in center when using mobile view-->
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active-home" href="{% url 'blog-homepage' %}">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-aboutpage' %}">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our project</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
  </section>


<!-- ================
  HEADER NAVIGATION/ENDED
========================= -->

    <div class="container">
        {%block homecontent%} {%endblock%}
        {%block aboutcontent%} {%endblock%}
    </div>   


<!-- footer -->
<!-- <h6>This is footer</h6> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the home.html in Django\mysite\blogapp\templates\blog\home.html .

```html
{%extends "blog/base.html"%}

{% block homecontent %}
    <div class="custom-card">
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
        <h3>By {{post.name}} on {{post.date}}</h3>
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        
    {% endfor %}
    </div>    
{% endblock homecontent %}
```

Below is the main.css in Django\mysite\blogapp\static\blog\main.css.
At the end, i'm trying to apply css on custom-card class. but its not working.

```css
.selector-for-some-widget {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  /*
  ================
  NAVIGATION
  ================
  */
  .header{
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .navbar-brand{
    color: black !important;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  .header .navbar-brand span{
    color: #FEAA01;
      font-weight: 700;
  
  }
  .navbar{
    padding-top: 20px ;
  }
  .fixed-top{
    background-color: #14111C;
    
    
  }
  .nav-item{
    /*padding: 5px;*/
    margin:8px 0px 10px 40px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
  }
  .nav-link{
    color: black !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px !important;
    display: unset;
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
  }
  .fa-bars{
    color: yellow;
    font-size: 30px !important;
  }
  .navbar-toggler{
    border: 0;
    padding: initial;
    outline: none;
  }
  .nav-link:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FEAA01;
    color: #FEAA01 !important;
  }
  .active-home{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  
  /*=============
    Navigation ended
  ===============*/
  
  .custom-card{
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

Comment: Did you try to clear browser history and reload your page?

Comment: ha-neul, Thanks bro. clearing the browser history has solved the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django CSS not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682812/django-css-not-updating)

Comment: Nope. Clearing the browser history has solved the problem. Thank you