# Sometimes website needs a refresh to show the website css django/python

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, django

Sometimes my website doesn't load css when redirected to other page. It needs to be refreshed to load and then it works fine. It doesn't happens everytime which is weird. I've seen some similar issues but none of them related to mine.

Other people also tested it in different pc's, the same thing happens.

Don't think it's a cache problem.

Website uses: Python/Django as backend.

How it looks like:
[image]

Network:
[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s hard to address the problem as the situation is some what not reproducible. My suggestion would be check the development tool in the browser and see if any error occurs.

Comment: Go to the Developer Tools in the Browser and see the ```network``` tap you must see what happen to the ```css``` files

Comment: dig this thread, a lot of hints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682812/django-css-not-updating

Comment: @Ayman that's the problem that there's no errors. Status is empty.

Comment: @EzonZhao no errors in network

Comment: Did you reload the page? Sometimes developer tools have to be open before you load the page. Status should never be empty. Even the page is perfectly OK, status shows OK at least.

Comment: @EzonZhao Yes, I leave dev tools open and in network side. I always do so, in order to see what's the issue. But nothing some some images being loaded with 200 code and css files show nothing. I updated my question.

Comment: I have the same issue, I can't see what is going on in network beacause to start recording net events it claims me to reload the page and then everything would work fine. I have my website deployed in production and this error still occurs. It happens to me when I close the chrome window with all tabs open and then reopen chrome. It is weird