# Button Still Disabled after page refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I have a button on a page:

```
<button class="" id="new_cat_charm">Add New Category</button>
```

I am using jquery to open a dialog box when the button is clicked and to add an overlay to the site:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
var newCatButton = $( '#new_cat_charm' );
newCatButton.click( function(){
    var newCatCharm = $( '#new-cat-charm' );
    newCatButton.prop( 'disabled', true );
    newCatCharm.removeClass( 'myhide' );
    appOverlay();
});

function appOverlay() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");
    $("#overlay").height(docHeight).css({
        'opacity' : 0.4,
        'position': 'absolute',
        'top': 0,
        'left': 0,
        'background-color': 'black',
        'width': '100%',
        'z-index': 5000
    });
}
});
```

After the button has been clicked I disable it and show the dialog box.

#### The problem

After I click on the button and it **becomes disabled** and the dialog box pops up, if I refresh the page the button **remains disabled** and I have to either do a **force reload** (ctrl+f5) or click inside the address bar of the browser and press enter before it returns to normal.

Comment: I think that's a cache problem. Have you tried using fiddler to debug?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5985839/875127)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using firefox? You may want to disable autocomplete: `autocomplete = "off"` in your button/inputs. Edit: see the SO question I linked to in the comments.

Comment: Yes I am using firefox. This worked fine. Thank you.