# Mobiscroll disables all input boxes on refresh

Tags: jquery, mobile, mobiscroll

I am using mobiscroll 2.1 on my web page. The problem that i am facing is that when i click on input button to see Mobiscroll and Mobiscroll widget pops up, now if i press F5 or refresh the page, instead of clicking Set or Cancel button, all the input fields are disabled.(This problem is only in firefox).

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this: ([Bug With Firefox - Disabled Attribute of Input Not Resetting When Refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985839/bug-with-firefox-disabled-attribute-of-input-not-resetting-when-refreshing)):

> This is a "feature" of Firefox which remembers form input values
>   across page refreshes. To fix this behavior, you simply set
>   autocomplete="off" on the form containing the inputs, or just directly
>   to the input.
>
> This stops autocomplete from working and prevents the browser from
>   remembering the state of input fields.