# div.disabled is not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have the below JavaScript which works fine in Internet Explorer(IE)

```
function disableDiv() {
    disablebutton(document.getElementById("pageWidth"))
}
function disablebutton(el) {
    try {
        el.disabled = el.disabled ? false : true;
    }
    catch (E) {
    }
}
```

and I'm calling this within a JavaScript function

```
function updatediv() {
    if (document.getElementById("sbtotals") != null) {
        document.getElementById("sbtotals").style.display = "none";
    }
    disableDiv();    
}
```

in IE `el.disable` works fine but not in Chrome or Firefox. 
What should I do to this to work in all 3 browsers?

Comment: @jAndy: Lol, I missed that while editing. I guess it was a typo for JavaScript.

Comment: Is 'pageWidth' an HTML button? Provide a piece of HTML code which contains an element with ID 'pageWidth'

Comment: @rushd: We have made some corrections to the question. Please check if they are inline with what you meant. Also show your HTML markup.

Comment: Check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985839/bug-with-firefox-disabled-attribute-of-input-not-resetting-when-refreshing

Comment: I guess this is a repeated question.
Please refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/639815/2134166.

You can create a class and add/remove it to disable/enable divs.

Answer (score 3):

Divs can't be disabled. Only form and form elems

Comment: Aren't fieldsets you're refering to? I didn't know that you could disable whole forms.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 'disable' a div. Instead you can set it's CSS display property to 'none'.

Comment: what i am realy tying to do is graying out the div for till while a some process are taken place. how can i grayout the div not hinde appreicate ur help

Comment: You can add an (absolute positioned) overlay div in the element on which you can apply some styling like opacity and background color. Make this element 100% height and 100% with and set it's display property to block when it needs to be displayed.